# Spring boot and EntityManager based on application.properties

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have following configuration file for Spring boot `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver    
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true  
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update 
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL   
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
```

It perfectly handled by spring `ddl-auto` creates tables for me. I expect it's enough information to create `EntityManager` from this 'DataSource'.

I found out that one of the ways to create `EntityManager` is:

```
EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "DataSorceGoesHere" );    
EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
```

**The questions are:**

1. What is the name of my datasource configured in `application.properties`?
2. Is there any opportunities to inject `EntityManager` based on `application.properties`?

Comment: You can inject the `EntityManagerFactory` directly. That one knows about your date source so only the second line is required, really.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll, could you please expand your question. I cannot `@Autowire EntityManagerFactory` context doesn't have appropriate interface for autowiring. What do you mean by `injection`?

Comment: I see, it's my IDE doesn't recognize it. All right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for the name  of the datasource I think that we can show it with the name of all the beans created with spring boot with this code

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("List of beans provided by Spring Boot:");
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.print(beanName);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```